# Testing inequality with nullable column in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

In LINQ is it safe to carry out an inequality test on a nullable column without having to convert the nullable type?

In T-SQL you have to use ISNULL().
But in LINQ can I safely do?:

```
mytable.nullablecol != 1
```

Comment: A concrete example would be fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to do it that way round.

EDIT: Given your comment, the problem is probably that `null == -1` has a result of null, not true (in SQL). So you could use a query of:

```
mytable.nullablecol != 1 || mytable.nullablecol == null
```

---

What becomes trickier is when you want to compare for equality with a value which *may* be null. You have to cater for that explicitly. For example:

```
int? x = GetId();
var query = from foo in bar
            where foo.X == x || (foo.X == null && x == null)
            select ...;
```

Comment: Ok thanks.  Just tried my example in LINQPad.  It seems to return all rows that != 1, but it will omit rows with nulls too?  I kind of hoped it would return those with null too since null != 1.

Comment: @jaffa: Editing... it's annoying, but easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Compile-time safe?  Yes.

Will null comparison filter rows you may not intend?  Yes.  It is done in the database by the database's rules.

```
foo.X != -1
```

This code will not give you the null X's. If you want those, you can isnull like this:

```
(foo.X ?? 0) != -1
```

or

```
(foo.HasValue ? foo : 0) != -1
```

---

Regarding "=" vs "is" query translations:

```
int? x = GetId();
var query = from foo in bar
  where foo.X == x
  select foo;
//LinqToSql examines the x 
 // you get an "is" comparison when x is null
 // you get an "=" comparison when x is not null
```

Where you may run into translation trouble is compiled queries.  Compiled queries cannot inspect their paramaters and adjust the translation.  In that case, you must make one compiled query for each case (two queries for one nullable parameter) and direct your parameters to the correct case's query.